# Measure reaction time

Tags: training, body-measurements

I want to measure my reaction time.

My goal  is to have a simple way to measure how fast I react.

Something like this:

- light on the left side, I press a button on the left side
- light on the right, I press a button on the right.

No running or big movements, just measure time from eye-input to finger/hand movement.

It can be an android app, an app for PC or a standalone device.

I want to practice at home and pay less than 80$.

I want a long term benchmark to see if I am getting better or not.

Background: I am learning tennis and I think my general reaction time is up to now not very good.

I want to check my reaction time daily to get a diagram like this in the long run:

[image]

Comment: If you want to improve your reaction time for tennis, play more tennis.

Comment: @JJosaur This question is about getting a numerical value for my reaction time. This way I can create a chart like in the image above.

Comment: @guettli JJosaur is right, however. Adaptations are to specific stimuli. This goes for muscle hypertrophy and doubly for neurological adaptations. Some things are useful in a general sense, such as strength and explosive power for better performance in sports. But if you practice reflexes by pressing buttons when a light comes up, you'll become good at pressing buttons when a light comes up. Not good at tennis. A large part of being good at that is anticipating an opponent's moves and understanding the ball's path, so your reflexes aren't the limiting factor to begin with. Invest time in that.

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to measure two different things from what I see in your question and confusingly they are not exactly the same:

1. The reaction time during your tennis games.
2. The general reaction time of the nervous system which the below links and applications measure.

The second point maybe will not translate ideally for measuring sports performance. You need to isolate your training with a machine for example, so it is repeatable, and then record your reaction times in order to check for improvements.

There is this site that I've used for the general nervous system reaction - http://www.humanbenchmark.com/tests/reactiontime

But as likely as everybody else will tell you, go play and train - that's how you're going to improve it. Physical training will over time strengthen the neural pathways in your brain and you will get some improvement.

I'm a runner and running made my reaction times with legs and balance really great - literally, I can count on my hand how many times a year I fell on my butt, even during the winter.

Here are some apps but they do the same as the website:

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.chingy1788.reactiontime&hl=en
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.qiwii.Reaction_Time&hl=en
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.SuperAwesome.Fastest&hl=en